# firestore subcollections add nodejs not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I tried to add a document for sub collection using nodejs , firestore is not adding the doc to the db, please let me know if it is a problem.

Sample code that is not working is as below

```
var data={
    Name    : "win",
    UID     : 2
    };
db = admin.firestore(my_app);
let colref=db.collection("X").doc("Y").collection("Z");
colref.add(data);
```

Comment: We can't see what's the value of `Y`, `Z` and `data`. Please edit your question to include that. It'll be easier for us to help you

Comment: Provide more code. What is "db" exactly? What you do after "add"?

Comment: Thanks , I have update the code sample, I will try to provide more details based on further questions

Comment: The code looks fine to me, so it's unlikely that the problem is in there (although we have no way of knowing what `my_app` is). Check your console for messages that seem related to your operation.